# If every group element has a fixed vector, does there exist a vector fixed by all?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G \leq SL(V)$ be a finite group where $V$ is a finite dimensional linear space over a finite field $k$, and assume that every element in $G$ has a nonzero fixed point in $V$, then is it necessary that there exist a nonzero point fixed by $G$ ?

I think in the case $dim V=2$, this is true. For example, if $G \leq SL_2(k)$, then one consider the fixed line $l_g$ for any $g \not =1 \in G$, then $l_g$ must be the same or one choose two lines as a basis then get a contradiction by considering the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, suppose $\operatorname{char} k\neq 2$, let $V=k^3$, and let $G\subseteq SL(V)$ be the subgroup generated by $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$  Explicitly, an element of $G$ is an even permutation matrix except that two of its $1$s may be changed to $-1$.  Every element of $G$ fixes some nonzero vector: if the permutation is the identity then some standard basis vector is fixed, if the permutation is a 3-cycle and there are no $-1$s then $(1,1,1)$ is fixed, and if the permutation is a 3-cycle and there are two $-1$s then some permutation of the vector $(1,1,-1)$ is fixed.  However, no nonzero vector is fixed by $G$ (the first generator only fixes scalar multiples of $(1,1,1)$, which are not fixed by the second generator).

Comment: I was approaching a very similar example, by starting with the canonical representation $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (in which every rotation has its axis as a fixed point), then taking a finite subgroup of $SO(3)$ such as the matrices which fix the union of the coordinate axes, then replacing $\mathbb{R}$ with a finite field with sufficient characteristic constraints and sufficient existence of roots of certain polynomials to enable the example still to work for that finite field.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: That was my inspiration too!  I was messing around with trying to show every element of $SO(3)$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ has a fixed point when I realized I could simplify things by just looking at this subgroup, which would work over any characteristic except $2$.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer !